# Change the server name in the HELO exchange in SQL Server Database Mail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail, database-mail

When my SQL Database mail connects to my SMTP provider it shows the local server name rather than the FQDN. I would like to find the configuration setting so that the HELO exchange uses the FQDN. For example, the email header shows the following:

```
# Received: from XXXXXXXXXXSQLSVR (unknown)
    by geopod-ismtpd-8 (SG) with ESMTP
    id hd6Gp5D_QYKF9OEZESI-tA
    Thu, 07 Sep 2023 18:49:36.406 +0000 (UTC)
```

and I would like it to be:

```
**Received: from MailServer.XYZDomain.com (111.111.111.111)**
    by geopod-ismtpd-8 (SG) with ESMTP
    id hd6Gp5D_QYKF9OEZESI-tA
    Thu, 07 Sep 2023 18:49:36.406 +0000 (UTC)
```

I have not been able to find a config setting anywhere that controls that HELO value.

Thank you

Comment: Not really helpful for the question. It is literally a function that has been in SQL Server forever and widely used to move data from the database to an SMTP provider.

Comment: I have used it for 15 years in a professional capacity and not had any issues with it. Over the years, probably 100s of apps/databases, using it for sending email from triggers or code. Never had any performance issues, but if you have some studies to prove me wrong, other than conjecture, I will take it into consideration. The only reason I am asking the question is because we are changing SMTP providers, and they show the server name in the header. Many ways to skin a cat...

Comment: I appreciate the non-down vote. It is a legit question, whether you agree with the philosophy or not. Probably won't get an answer with the downvote, I would expect. As for the trigger, a trigger makes a sql call based on conditions, like calling a stored procedure, which is exactly what the sql mail call is. I don't really see the issue. It literally inserts data into a table for the mail function to pickup. Whether it inserts it into a local table or a table in msdb, i don't see the difference.

Comment: The SMTP function is complete separate from the trigger action. The only thing the trigger does is insert the data into the mail table via the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure. There are no SMTP functions done in that process. As a separate function, the database mail service polls the table to see if there is mail to send and then connect to the smtp service as a client and sends it. Thanks

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the back and forth. I agree that it is not an email system. It is just a client that sends the mail through SendGrid (as an example). Thanks again...I think I will consider this a loss and go to the MS forums....which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: The mail is sent by an external .NET-based program, `databasemail.exe`, that uses a `System.Net.SmtpClient` to do the protocol exchange. Unless you can specify the EHLO/HELO host in the `databasemail.exe.config` file there's not likely much you can do about it.

Comment: The log lines shown in the question will be coming from a receiving mail server. Probably you need to think of this from a DNS perspective... do you have a reverse DNS (PTR) entry for your SQL Server's public IP address(es)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I can fudge it to use a shared IP on the external network that the outside world sees that the traffic is coming from. I will take a look at the config file. Thanks.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/network-element-network-settings#attributes `clientDomain` attribute

Comment: Reading this a couple of times, it seems this question can be isolated down to a SMTP server config question since it can be reproduced by connecting to the SMTP server from a terminal somewhere without SQL in the mix. Or am I misunderstanding? Or is this issue specific to the specific client that SQL Server uses?

Comment: @Nick.Mc Yes it's specific to the client, as that is the one that does the `HELO` command (not to be confused with the `EHLO` response by the SMTP server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is going to work, as I haven't tested it, but since `DatabaseMail.exe` is the application that actually sends the emails, and it uses `SmtpClient` apparently, you can try adding to the XML configuration file at `DatabaseMail.exe.config`. This is located in your SQL Server instance location, in a folder called `Binn`.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network clientDomain="MailServer.XYZDomain.com" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

There will presumably already be a `<configuration>` node, so just merge it togther.

More settings can be seen [here in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/smtp-element-network-settings), do note that the application will probably overwite most of them from its own config in the `msdb` database.

Don't forget to restart the DBMail service after the changes.

Comment: You are a rockstar! Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: It is important to note that the database mail service must be stopped and restarted after the configuration changes have been made, if the database mail service was running when the changes were made. This can be done with the "EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_stop_sp" and "EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp" commands.